# Magento2 : Get Customer Phone number in Abandoned Cart Reports

Tags: magento2.4

Currently core magento2 gives Customer name, email, qty, subtotal, created, updated, applied coupon and ip address in Abandoned cart reports.

It is in Admin panel. Reports > Marketing > Abandoned Cart Reports

Here I want to add an additional field for phone number in magento2 abandoned carts grid and export as well...plz help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create module.
**Vendor_Name = {{Vendor}}  and Module_Name= {{Phone}}**

1. Create **registration.php** under **Vendor/Phone** folder

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
 \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Vendor_Phone',
    __DIR__
);
```

2. Create **module.xml** file under the etc folder **Vendor/Phone/etc/module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_Phone" setup_version="1.0.1"></module>
</config>
```

3. Create **di.xml** under the **Vendor/Phone/etc/adminhtml/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Reports\Block\Adminhtml\Shopcart\Abandoned\Grid" type="Vendor\Phone\Block\Adminhtml\Shopcart\Abandoned\Grid" />
</config>
```

4. Create **Grid.php** under the **Vendor/Phone/Block/Adminhtml/Shopcart/Abandoned**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Vendor\Phone\Block\Adminhtml\Shopcart\Abandoned;


/**
 * Adminhtml abandoned shopping carts report grid block
 *
 * @method \Magento\Reports\Model\ResourceModel\Quote\Collection getCollection()
 *
 * @author      Magento Core Team <core@magentocommerce.com>
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.DepthOfInheritance)
 */
class Grid extends \Magento\Reports\Block\Adminhtml\Grid\Shopcart
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Reports\Model\ResourceModel\Quote\CollectionFactory
     */
    protected $_quotesFactory;


    /**
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Helper\Data $backendHelper
     * @param \Magento\Reports\Model\ResourceModel\Quote\CollectionFactory $quotesFactory
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Backend\Helper\Data $backendHelper,
        \Magento\Reports\Model\ResourceModel\Quote\CollectionFactory $quotesFactory,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_quotesFactory = $quotesFactory;
        parent::__construct($context, $backendHelper, $data);
    }


    /**
     * Grid constructor
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->setId('gridAbandoned');
    }


    /**
     * Prepare collection
     *
     * @return \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid
     */
    protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        /** @var $collection \Magento\Reports\Model\ResourceModel\Quote\Collection */
        $collection = $this->_quotesFactory->create();


        $filter = $this->getParam($this->getVarNameFilter(), []);
        if ($filter) {
            $filter = base64_decode($filter);
            parse_str(urldecode($filter), $data);
        }


        if (!empty($data)) {
            $collection->prepareForAbandonedReport($this->_storeIds, $data);
        } else {
            $collection->prepareForAbandonedReport($this->_storeIds);
        }


        $this->setCollection($collection);
        parent::_prepareCollection();
        if ($this->_isExport) {
            $collection->setPageSize(null);
        }
        $this->getCollection()->resolveCustomerNames();
        return $this;
    }


    /**
     * Add column filter to collection
     *
     * @param array $column
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function _addColumnFilterToCollection($column)
    {
        $field = $column->getFilterIndex() ? $column->getFilterIndex() : $column->getIndex();
        $skip = ['subtotal', 'customer_name', 'email'];


        if (in_array($field, $skip)) {
            return $this;
        }


        parent::_addColumnFilterToCollection($column);
        return $this;
    }


    /**
     * Prepare columns
     *
     * @return \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Extended
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength)
     */
    protected function _prepareColumns()
    {
        $this->addColumn(
            'customer_name',
            [
                'header' => __('Customer'),
                'index' => 'customer_name',
                'sortable' => false,
                'header_css_class' => 'col-name',
                'column_css_class' => 'col-name'
            ]
        );


        $this->addColumn(
            'email',
            [
                'header' => __('Email'),
                'index' => 'email',
                'sortable' => false,
                'header_css_class' => 'col-email',
                'column_css_class' => 'col-email'
            ]
        );


         $this->addColumn(
            'phone',
            [
                'header' => __('Phone'),
                'index' => 'phone',
                'sortable' => false,
                'renderer' => \Vendor\Phone\Block\Adminhtml\Grid\Column\Renderer\Phone::class,
                'header_css_class' => 'col-email',
                'column_css_class' => 'col-email'
            ]
        );


        $this->addColumn(
            'items_count',
            [
                'header' => __('Products'),
                'index' => 'items_count',
                'sortable' => false,
                'type' => 'number',
                'header_css_class' => 'col-number',
                'column_css_class' => 'col-number'
            ]
        );


        $this->addColumn(
            'items_qty',
            [
                'header' => __('Quantity'),
                'index' => 'items_qty',
                'sortable' => false,
                'type' => 'number',
                'header_css_class' => 'col-qty',
                'column_css_class' => 'col-qty'
            ]
        );


        if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('website')) {
            $storeIds = $this->_storeManager->getWebsite($this->getRequest()->getParam('website'))->getStoreIds();
        } elseif ($this->getRequest()->getParam('group')) {
            $storeIds = $this->_storeManager->getGroup($this->getRequest()->getParam('group'))->getStoreIds();
        } elseif ($this->getRequest()->getParam('store')) {
            $storeIds = [(int)$this->getRequest()->getParam('store')];
        } else {
            $storeIds = [];
        }
        $this->setStoreIds($storeIds);
        $currencyCode = $this->getCurrentCurrencyCode();


        $this->addColumn(
            'subtotal',
            [
                'header' => __('Subtotal'),
                'type' => 'currency',
                'currency_code' => $currencyCode,
                'index' => 'subtotal',
                'sortable' => false,
                'renderer' => \Magento\Reports\Block\Adminhtml\Grid\Column\Renderer\Currency::class,
                'rate' => $this->getRate($currencyCode),
                'header_css_class' => 'col-subtotal',
                'column_css_class' => 'col-subtotal'
            ]
        );


        $this->addColumn(
            'coupon_code',
            [
                'header' => __('Applied Coupon'),
                'index' => 'coupon_code',
                'sortable' => false,
                'header_css_class' => 'col-coupon',
                'column_css_class' => 'col-coupon'
            ]
        );


        $this->addColumn(
            'created_at',
            [
                'header' => __('Created'),
                'type' => 'datetime',
                'index' => 'created_at',
                'filter_index' => 'main_table.created_at',
                'sortable' => false,
                'header_css_class' => 'col-created',
                'column_css_class' => 'col-created'
            ]
        );


        $this->addColumn(
            'updated_at',
            [
                'header' => __('Updated'),
                'type' => 'datetime',
                'index' => 'updated_at',
                'filter_index' => 'main_table.updated_at',
                'sortable' => false,
                'header_css_class' => 'col-updated',
                'column_css_class' => 'col-updated'
            ]
        );


        $this->addColumn(
            'remote_ip',
            [
                'header' => __('IP Address'),
                'index' => 'remote_ip',
                'sortable' => false,
                'header_css_class' => 'col-ip',
                'column_css_class' => 'col-ip'
            ]
        );


        $this->addExportType('*/*/exportAbandonedCsv', __('CSV'));
        $this->addExportType('*/*/exportAbandonedExcel', __('Excel XML'));


        return parent::_prepareColumns();
    }


    /**
     * Get rows url
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\DataObject $row
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getRowUrl($row)
    {
        return $this->getUrl('customer/index/edit', ['id' => $row->getCustomerId(), 'active_tab' => 'cart']);
    }
}
```

5. Create **Phone.php** under the **Vendor/Phone/Block/Adminhtml/Grid/Column/Renderer/Phone.php**

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Phone\Block\Adminhtml\Grid\Column\Renderer;
use Magento\Backend\Block\Context;
use Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory;
use Magento\Framework\DataObject;
use Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Api\AddressRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
/**
 * Adminhtml Report Customers Reviews renderer
 *
 * @author      Magento Core Team <core@magentocommerce.com>
 */
class Phone extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column\Renderer\AbstractRenderer
{
    protected $_customerFactory;
    protected $_storeManager;
    public function __construct(
        CustomerFactory $customerFactory,
        UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory,
        CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository,
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        Context $context,
        array $data = []
    )
        {
            $this->_customerFactory = $customerFactory;
            $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
            parent::__construct($context, $data);
        }
    /**
     * Renders grid column
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\DataObject $row
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Phrase|string
     */
    public function render(\Magento\Framework\DataObject $row)
    {
         $id = $row->getCustomerId();
         $customer_email = $row->getCustomerEmail();
         $currentWebsiteId = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getWebsiteId();
         $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
            /* Create a new product object */
            $customer = $objectManager->create(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::class);
            $Address = $objectManager->get(\Magento\Customer\Api\AddressRepositoryInterface::class);
            $customer->setWebsiteId($currentWebsiteId);
            $customer->loadByEmail($customer_email);
            $billingAddressId = $customer->getDefaultBilling();
            $shippingAddressId = $customer->getDefaultShipping();
            //get default billing address
                try {
                    $billingAddress = $Address->getById($billingAddressId);
                    $telephone = $billingAddress->getTelephone();
                    return $telephone;
                } catch (\Exception $e) {
                    //
                    return null;
                }
    }
}
```